# ListDensityPlot do not show the exact color

Tags: plotting

I use ListDensityPlot to plot a density contour, but it has some wrong white color.

How can I fix them?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. People here generally like users to post code/formulas as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find this [meta Q&A](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) helpful. As for your actual problem: White/Empty areas show that the values there are either not real numbers, or that they lie outside the plot range. I suggest you try `PlotRange->All`

Comment: After I add PlotRange->All to the command it works, thank you so much. Because the function I use is defined in a complicate way so I just want to post the figures, I grab the screen which include the codes. Sorry for making puzzles. Next time I will follow the rules about asking questions.